# regex to find out contents within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

`'"key":"value"'` I have the following string and I want to strip out `key` and `value`. What should be the `regex` for this?

`/"(.*?)"/g` returns `"key"` and `"value"`. I am interested in `key` and `value` without the `"`s.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely this is the right way to do this. You're probably dealing with JSON. In that case, just parse the JSON, as in `JSON.parse('{"key":"value"}')`.

Comment: `var str = '"key":"value"';
var obj = JSON.parse("{" + str + "}");
var key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
var val = obj[key];
console.log(key, val);`

Comment: If you still want a regex, `/"(.+)":"(.+)"/` should do the work.

Comment: So from that trivial answer linked, it looks like `".*?"` is the mindless way to do it.

Comment: @sln `/"(.*?)"/g` returns `"key"` and `"value"`. I am interested in `key` and `value` w/o the `"`

Comment: @sarbbottam - I can only assume you are new to regular expressions. `I am interested in ..` is why there are capture groups.

Comment: `/[^":]+/g` might work

Comment: @sln you are correct, I am new to regex and thus struggling.

Comment: to explain my commenet further: `[...]` creates a character class.  `[^...]` makes it a negative match (exclude any `"` and `:` characters).  `+` means one or more characters to match.  `g` means make it global.

Comment: Thanks @JosephMarikle `/([^":]+)/g` captures every thing w/o `"`. My string is not exactly `'"key":"value"'` but `'    "key":  "value",'`

Comment: @sarbbottam - Capture groups _capture_ the sub-expression data within the parenthesis. They are numbered sequentially from left to right as found in your expression. You can access them after the match via some index 1,2,3, etc. _Capture Group 0_ is a special buffer than contains the entire match. Example `"(.*?)"`, here group 0 contains `"key"` and group 1 contains `key`.

Comment: If it means anything, `(?<=").*?(?=")` would make group 0 now contain `key`. But, like a jacked up regex engine JS uses, there are no lookbehind assertions, so `(?<=")` will throw an error. Accept that you always have to work around this messed up engine. Use the capture groups, and try not to get disgusted !

Comment: Thanks @sln, I guess I have use `/"(.*?)"/g` and then strip off `"`.